# Apache will not serve Django static files

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, httpd.conf

So I've seen alot about Apache not serving Django admin static files, but for some reason, Apache is not serving any static files.  It understands and finds the templates, but no images, css, or javascript is loaded.

EDIT 2: Updated the two files to show new settings

EDIT: I added the STATIC_ROOT and I was able to collectstatic files, but it still doesn't serve them after server restart.

<strike>I've tried ./manage.py collectstatic and get this error:</strike>

```
ImproperlyConfigured("You're using the staticfiles app "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without 
having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.
```

My settings.py file is here:

https://github.com/rchurch4/stackquestions/blob/master/settings.py

My nxt4.com.conf file is here:

https://github.com/rchurch4/stackquestions/blob/master/nxt4.com.conf

If someone could please let me know exactly how to configure this so that Apache will serve django's static files, that would be great.  I'm running Ubuntu on AWS with a mysql db.  The filepath to the site on the server is: /home/ubuntu/nxt4.com/nxt4/

Thanks in advance

Comment: You say you've added `STATIC_ROOT` - you haven't added it to the `settings.py` you linked. Also, show your _actual_ settings?

Comment: what do you mean by actual settings?  Completely new to the web server thing, so the more specific the better.  If by actual settings you mean /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/nxt4.com.conf, then it's in the newest edit that will be up as soon as I enter this comment...

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems quite clear: you have not set the `STATIC_ROOT` setting, so collectstatic does not know where to put the collected files. From the looks of your httpd.conf, it seems like it should be set to "/home/ubuntu/nxt4.com/static/"

Comment: I was able to collectstatic files in the root, but it still doesn't serve them